# Apns Push topic with http2

Tags: apple-push-notifications, push, http2

Currently I am using socked based communication with Apple for sending push notifications . For this we just need to specify APNS certificate , device token and payload to Apple cloud and it will send push to corresponding device.

Problem:
Now we are migrating to new API of Apple using Http2 to send push notifications . Their document suggests that if a certificate have multiple push topics we need to specify 'apns-topic' . If we don't provide that header then we will get an error saying 'missing topic'.

My question is I am using same certificate with multiple topics with old version of APNS there it will not ask me any apns-topic header . Then how will apple decide to which topic it should send  push notification in old API . Why is it asking now in new API for apns-topic .

Every certificate will almost have multiple topic for iwatch complication and voip servcies for a given app . If a app has bundle id like com.a.b then we will have topics like

com.a.b , com.a.b.voip , com.a.b.complication

Is there any way to skip anps-topic header if certificate have multiple push topics using Http2 API of APNS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't use VoIP and Watch push notifications with an old APNS server, so that's why there is no need to provide topics.